# how to get cellvalue in datagrid, on mouse double click event in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I am new in wpf.

I am binding below datagrid in wpf

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
          Loaded="dataGrid1_Loaded" 
          MouseDoubleClick="dataGrid1_MouseDoubleClick" 
          Height="350" 
          Width="1200"
          Name="dataGrid1" />
```

I have one "OID" name column in the grid, and I want to get the value of this column when user double click on row.
How can I get it ? which event I should use for it ?

I can use view button in datagrid to get column value, but I don't know how to bind buttons/link in datagrid and how to handle it for get column value ?

Thanks
C.P

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you are about to develop a pretty big (over 1 week of development) application you really should start thinking about [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel).

In this architecture you wont use event handlers in the code behind. instead, you will use
[`Commands`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238657/How-to-use-Commands-in-WPF) to send info from your UI to your logic, and [`Bindings`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140621/WPF-Tutorial-Concept-Binding) from logic to the UI.

But to answer your current question, you can use the `MouseDoubleClick` event and retrieve your data from there

```
    private void DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = sender as DataGrid;

        var cellValue = grid.SelectedValue;
    }
```

This will get the value when the user double clicks the row in the specific column.
If you want to get the value of the cell no matter where the user double clicked the row, use:

`grid.SelectedItem`

to get the object that the row represents, and from there retreive your property your column is binded to.

Hope this helps

Comment: it's very tough to get column value from grid.SelectedItem

Comment: @ChhatrapatiSharma if the datagrid is binded to some collection source, each row is a single item in the collection and each column is a property in that item. So, basically, the value of a column in a specific row, is the value of the property that column is binded to. `grid.SelectedItem` gives you the item selected on the row so accessing the property you want is as simple as it gets ...